# Condition on function $\Phi$ to get subspace of Orlicz space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, function-spaces, orlicz-spaces

Let me define it first
**Definition 1:** A mapping $\Phi:\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R^+}$ is said to be an N function if
(1) $\Phi$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^+}$
(2) $\Phi$ is convex
(3) $\Phi(x)=0$ iff $x=0$
(4) $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\Phi(x)}{x}=0$
(5) $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\Phi(x)}{x}=\infty$

**Orlicz space:** Let $(\Omega,F,\mu)$ be arbitrary measure space.Then the orlicz space is defined as
$$\tag{1}
L^{\Phi}(\mu)=\Big\{f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R} \hspace{0.2cm} \text{such that} \int_{\Omega}\Phi(|\alpha f|)\,\mathrm d\mu<\infty \mbox{ for some } \alpha>0\Big\}
$$
What we have is that $L^{\Phi}$ is a normed linear space with the norm
$$
\|f\|_{\Phi} = \inf\Big\{k>0:\int_{\Omega}\Phi(\tfrac{f}{k})\,\mathrm d\mu\leq 1\Big\}
$$

**My Question:** I want to generate a subspace of $L^{\Phi}$ and look for its property. My idea is to put some conditions on $\Phi$ to get the subspace. I was thinking of putting some condition on $\Phi$ such that it will be non-zero in some interval $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ and zero otherwise. But think if I do this then this will contradict the property $(3)$ that $\Phi$ is satisfying. Now suppose I modified (3) such that $\Phi(0)=0$ then if I define $\Phi$ as I said above will it still be convex? I think then it will not be convex anymore(Not sure). Can someone clarify this also if someone can help to find some condition on $\Phi$ such that we get subspace,that will be great help.I am trying to understand Orlicz space deeply.

Comment: Any normed space $X$ with dimension >1 has non trivial subspaces.Take $x\in X$ and let $V=\{\lambda x: \lambda\in \mathbb{F}\}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is the field over which you are taking linear combinations. There is nothing in particular about $\Phi$. In previous postings of yours some answerers have given you concrete examples of some subspaces of $L^\Phi$ that are a little more sophisticated.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your answer, actually what I am trying to do is to search for some subspace of $L^{\Phi}$ and look for some properties of it like a subspace that is not Banach or maybe a subspace which will be dense in $L^{\Phi}$, or any other properties. Can you suggest to me some approach for this.

Comment: When the measure is finite $L_\infty$ is a subset of any Orlicz space, and under certain conditions on $\Phi$ it is actually dense. Look for concrete examples. There are many books on Orlicz spaces, maybe you should take a look at one of them (B. Simon's complex analysis deduces a chapter on them) to get more of a feeling for them.

Comment: can you provide link to the book that you have mentioned

Comment: Sure, [here](http://math.caltech.edu/Convexity.html)

Comment: Thanks.I will go through it to understand more about $L^{\Phi}$